# How to rotate array matrix n x n by k times?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have currently made a 90-degree rotation but I don't know how to enter any number of rotations.
For example:
 1. grid = n * n
 2. K = number of rotations

I can only make it spin once, now I have to do so that K can be a dynamic number.

This is my code!

```html
function rotate() {
  var matrix = [[0,16,255,1],[8,128,32,1],[0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1]];
  const N = matrix.length - 1;   // use a constant
  // use arrow functions and nested map;
  const result = matrix.map((row, i) => 
       row.map((val, j) => matrix[N - j][i])
  );
  matrix.length = 0;       // hold original array reference
  matrix.push(...result);  // Spread operator
  console.log(matrix);
  return matrix;
}
```

Comment: `rotate(rotate())` to rotate twice?

Comment: Hi, number of rotations to be entered by the user.

Comment: @JonasWilms number of rotations to be entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

my proposal...

```js
Array.prototype.Rotate = function(RotateNumber)
  {
  let len = this.length

  for (let l of this)
    {
    if ( !Array.isArray(l))  throw "this is not a matrix !"
    if (l.length!==len)      throw "this is not a square matrix !"
    }

  let r = RotateNumber %4   // max 3 rotates
  if (r<0) r +=4           // for negative rotates

  for(n=r;n--;)
    {
    let temp = this.map((r,i,A)=>
                { 
                let t=[]
                for(let j=A.length;j--;) t.push(A[j][i])
                return t 
                })
    this.forEach((r,i)=>r.forEach((c,j)=>this[i][j]=temp[i][j])) // copy values
    }
  return this
  }


///////////////////////////////////// test part ///////////////////
function matrixDisplay(comment,matrix)
  {
  let prev = '[ ' 
  console.log(comment, ' =')

  for(let line of matrix)
    {
    console.log ( prev + '[ ' + line.map(col=>`'${col}'`).join(', ') + ' ]' )
    prev = ', '
    }
  console.log(']')
  }
  
  var matrix = 
      [ [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ] 
      , [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ] 
      , [ 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'W' ] 
      , [ '8', '7', '6', '5' ] 
      ] 


matrixDisplay('matrix start', matrix ,3)
matrixDisplay('matrix R2',    matrix.Rotate(2),3)
matrixDisplay('matrix R-3',   matrix.Rotate(-3),3)
matrixDisplay('matrix R1',    matrix.Rotate(1),3)
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```